# magento 2 how to generate invoice with specific amount

Tags: magento2

I want to generate invoice with specific amount, anyone have idea how can we generate invoice with specific amount ?

Answer (score 1):

At Magento, you cannot generate a specific amount Wise.

> Magento invoice order amount depends on NO of Invoice  Qty.
>
> invoice = Unitprice1 of an order item A *NoOfInvoiuceQty*

Give an example an order

```
Item A:  Qty: 2   unit price: 50
Item B:  Qty: 1 Unit unit price: 100
```

**Then  you can maximum 3 Invoice and mini 1**

Like

**InvoiceA**

```
item A:  Qty: 1   unit price: 50
```

**invoice B**

```
item A:  Qty: 1   unit price: 50
```

**Invoice C**

```
item B:  Qty: 1   unit price: 100
```

Comment: ok so how we can add shipping amount to Invoice ?

Comment: Shipping method is automatically assign to invoice